# JQuery API Doc generator for typescript custom Widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, documentation, typescript

I have some custom typescript Widget have to create a API doc for that. I have searched a lot but i didn't find anything useful.
Is there is any tool for generate a API doc like [Jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/)

**Note:**  I have used [Natural Docs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) for my jquery custom widget, but i can't use it in typescript custom widget. Is there any way to use that for typescript.

Any suggestions should be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

So far I think there is no official support for any documentation lib integrated into typescript.

Typescript supports [jsdoc](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/01/21/announcing-typescript-0-8-2.aspx).
This means you should use jsdoc style documentation for your typescripts.

I think the compiler should also have an option to add your ts comments into the js files. This should enable you to at least document your javascript API, which is more or less what others might need/use to integrate your APIs anyways.